# Using some code to clone objects but I also need the code to call the constructor which it doesn't

Tags: c#, serialization

I have been messing around with the following code (from http://naspinski.net/post/Cloning-an-Entity-in-Linq-to-Entities.aspx):

```
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        var dcs = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(ms, source);
            ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

This works well....except that it doesn't call the constructor.  Basically I have a constructor that takes in no parameters that I would like the code above to call.  Is there a way to somehow call that constructor?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't know what the original title was, but the edited title makes no sense.

Comment: If the class implements `ISerializable` the constructor `ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can implement `OnDeserializing` to do you initialization, this is one your options:

```
[OnDeserializing]
void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext c)
{
    //create what is required here
}
```

Comment: The only problem with that is the class is auto created and the public constructor calls private methods.  So even if I did that I  still wouldn't be able to call those auto created private methods.